# Why there isn't any file and folder except 'node_modules' and 'package.json' anymore when creating a project with 'npx create-react-app' command?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I created a react project with the 'npx create-react-app my-app' command before and the 'my-app' folder contains this files and folders:

```
my-app
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

But now when I create a react project with the same command, the 'my-app' folder contains only 'node_modules' folder and 'package.json' 'yarn.lock' files.

```
my-app
├── node_modules
├── yarn.lock
└── package.json
```

I thought probably for using an outdated version of create-react-app, then to fix this, I did the following steps:

1. Removing the old version of CRA by running `npm rm -g create-react-app`
2. Installing the new version globally by running `npm install -g create-react-app`

But my issue still existed. The last thing that came to my mind was upgrading node.js from v10 to v12.16.3, but nothing didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred because there is global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported.
For solving this problem, run these command respectively:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then install `create-react-app` in this way

```
npm install create-react-app
```

Then create your react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```