# public, src,and scripts folder not created while installing react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

`npx create-react-app client`**when I tried to install react app using npx the files src,  public folder are not created cmd is shown below**[image: src, public folders are not created while installing react app. I tried many solutions but don't work out. I tried to remove react app globally and reinstalled then also it's not creating. installation not being successful. Earlier I created a react for a project but now it is not working as expected.]

My react installation not being successful. Its been 2-3 days I'm searching for solution gone through many solutions but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: You need to provide more details on what you are trying to attempt. What is the error, output if any and details to arrive at a solution. Think from a person who does not know what you are working at and have to explain to us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update node.js and react-app.
Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357754/why-there-isnt-any-file-and-folder-except-node-modules-and-package-json-any) maybe useful.

Comment: pls, see the link that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I had gone through the link but still its happening on my side.